# How to execute a prolog query which I got from a http parameter in SWIProlog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm writing a webservice in SWI Prolog. In which I would send my query as GET parameter and the service would return the result in JSON.

This is my code:

```
handle_query(Request) :-
http_parameters(Request, [ query(Query, []) ]), % Query to execute
```

An example query:

`father(Father, raghav), wife(Mother, Father).`

How can I achieve something like this?

Reason for making a webservice and communicating over HTTP is that there aren't any good interface available for Python. SWI Prolog has a great http library so I though I'd use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a Prolog query has a natural representation as a Prolog term, so you can always use `call/1` to execute an arbitrary Prolog goal. You can use JSON to pass Prolog terms via HTTP.

Using SWI-Prolog's `safe_goal/1`, you can also test the safety of the goal before calling it.

In SWI-Prolog, also check out [Pengines](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pengines/index.txt), which nicely encapsulate such common client/server scenarios.

Comment: You can only execute one predicate using call. And when I use it it considers query as string and returns `Undefined procedure: 'father(raghav, S)'/0`

Comment: You can execute any Prolog predicate using `call/1`, including *conjunctions*, as in `call((A,B))` and *disjunctions* as in `call((A;B))`. You need to represent the goal so that it matches the natural Prolog representation of goals. See the term conversion predicates for more information.